# TSQL Update value to 1 if Max value between two table else 0

Tags: t-sql, max

I have two table

```
TABLE 1 : Stage_product
PRODUCT_ID      SYS_ROWDATETIMEUTC  
1                2015-03-13 06:09:30.040
2                ....
3


TABLE 2 : DIM_Product
PRODUCT_ID      SYS_ROWSTARTDATETIMEUTC       SYS_ROWISCURRENT
1               2014-03-13 06:09:30.040            0
2               2015-03-13 06:09:30.040            1
```

I want to do an update statement that if the value `SYS_ROWDATETIMEUTC` in the first table is more recent than the value `SYS_ROWSTARTDATETIMEUTC` in the table, then the value `SYS_ROWISCURRENT` in the second table is set to 0, else 1.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following query:

```
UPDATE t2
SET t2.SYS_ROWISCURRENT = CASE 
                            WHEN t1.SYS_ROWDATETIMEUTC > t2.SYS_ROWSTARTDATETIMEUTC THEN 0
                            ELSE 1
                          END   
FROM Table2 t2
INNER JOIN Table1 t1 ON t2.PRODUCT_ID = t1.PRODUCT_ID
```

I assume you want to compare dates between the two tables for *the same product*.